Appending a dictionary to a list with the same key and different values
After extracting data from a website, I want to print it out as a dictionary in a list but the output only brings out the first iteration of the whole loop instead of printing out all the whole loop iteration.
Here is my code:
list = []
for item in data:
        
        dictionary = {}
        dictionary['Address'] = item.find('div',{'class':'property-address'}).text.replace(' ','').strip()    
            
        dictionary['Locality'] = item.find('div',{'class':'property-city'}).text.replace(' ','').strip()
        dictionary['Beds'] = item.find('div',{'class':'property-beds'}).find('strong').text
        try:
            dictionary['Baths'] = item.find('div',{'class':'property-baths'}).find('strong').text
        except:
                pass  
        try: 
            dictionary['Square Feet'] = item.find('div',{'class':'property-sqft'}).find('strong').text
        except:
                pass     
        dictionary['Price'] = item.find('a',{'class':'listing-price'}).text.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
        

list.append(dictionary)

After executing the code I was expecting the list to print out all the iteration of the loop, but instead the dictionary only prints out the first iteration instead of all.
[{'Address': '924MaltmanAve',
  'Locality': 'LosAngelesCA90026',
  'Beds': '1',
  'Baths': '1',
  'Square Feet': '676',
  'Price': '$825,000'}]

Instead it was supposed to be like
[{'Address': '924MaltmanAve',
  'Locality': 'LosAngelesCA90026',
  'Beds': '1',
  'Baths': '1',
  'Square Feet': '676',
  'Price': '$825,000'},
{'Address': '3055NicholsCanyonRd',
  'Locality': 'LosAngelesCA90046',
  'Beds': '5',
  'Baths': '4',
  'Square Feet': '776',
  'Price': '$3,950,000'},
{'Address': '3055NicholsCanyonRd',
  'Locality': 'LosAngelesCA90046',
  'Beds': '5',
  'Baths': '4',
  'Square Feet': '776',
  'Price': '$3,950,000'}]

And the sequence follows.
But the output only gave me the first iteration of the whole iteration.

You probably want to indent your list.append to be within your loop, otherwise you'll end up with only the last dictionary in your list.

Change the indentation of list.append to right. Also:

don't use built-in names such as list (it shadows Python's list).
don't use try: except: pass, handle the missing elements with if ... else

lst = []  # <-- don't use `list` as variable name
for item in data:

    dictionary = {}

    dictionary["Address"] = (
        item.find("div", {"class": "property-address"}).text.replace(" ", "").strip()
    )

    dictionary["Locality"] = (
        item.find("div", {"class": "property-city"}).text.replace(" ", "").strip()
    )
    dictionary["Beds"] = (
        item.find("div", {"class": "property-beds"}).find("strong").text
    )

    baths = item.select_one("div.property-baths strong")  # <-- don't use try: except: pass
    dictionary["Baths"] = baths.text if baths else "-"

    sfeet = item.select_one("div.property-sqft strong")
    dictionary["Square Feet"] = sfeet.text if sfeet else "-"

    dictionary["Price"] = (
        item.find("a", {"class": "listing-price"})
        .text.replace("\n", "")
        .replace(" ", "")
    )

    lst.append(dictionary)  # <-- note the indentation

